# System catch emails

Tags: php, cloud, laravel, email

Currently i'm building a system (custom CMS) and the requirement is to catch all the emails sent by public to registered email address, and reply via the email address through the system via the registered email as well.

For example:

1. i set it to info@stackoverflow.com, then when slim@slim.com sent email to info@stackoverflow.com
2. my system will catch it and display the email with attachment to the group
3. Who handle the email will generate a "randomHashTemp"@stackoverflow.com to identify who handling the case
4. system will reply via "randomHashTemp"@stackoverflow.com (like google group)
5. Communicate continue via "randomHashTemp"@stackoverflow.com

BUT

1. if user sent to else@stackoverflow.com then will be catch by their current email server like exchange

i don't know the term of this called. May i know how can i implement it? please advice with some links or keywords. i knew a lot of knowledgebase solution, CRM, project management software integrated through CNAME, changing DNS those stuff, but i got no idea on how. Thanks.

**Update**

The sample would be something like http://www.cloudmailin.com
but what i want is generate from my app and receive the emails from public for my clients.

Comment: Have you looked at something like the inbound email API from [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) ... basically, you configure inbound email MX records to point to Mandrill, any new emails received at the defined email addresses are forwarded to your app via the API. Not sure if that's the kind of info you are looking for?

Comment: @SimonHampel, is it possible to make it random receiver? i want to implement something like google group, or comment on google doc, or some famous knowledge base system. while once a ticket open via user emailed to info@abc.com, then they can internally generate a new receiver like slim+32jhwus9@abc.com to handle the case.

Comment: I want know about this one. see the link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: @Nytram, is this suitable for something like cloud solution and streaming all mailbox of customers? i'm not really understand imap-open honestly.

Comment: Usually you add a ticket number to the address, like info+ticket012345@example.com, then communicate with this address; BTW. "Expecting a working solution" does not quite fit the QA format of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @dualed, sorry that's my mistake! I notice after I submit the bounty and I can't edit anymore :/ I need keyword to do research, I need some guide on how to do it :) thanks

Comment: Have you looked at existing issue tracking systems? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_help_desk_issue_tracking_software

Comment: If you implement a catch-all email address for the domain and then process any addressing in your code, then you can use whatever addressing scheme you choose. So slim+32jhwus9@abc.com would just automatically be passed to your code and you parse out the unique identifier to associate the inbound email with the appropriate thread or issue or whatever.

Comment: check this out http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replied my question!! After researches of couple days, finally i get sort of clue. Here is a compiled answer to the question.

First, Implement [fMailbox](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox) to the system. [Thanks to @Nytram, please answer as a question for me to give you the 50 reputations. this link meant a lot!] To achieve it mail receiving function. This method no need touching email server, no need touching system environment itself, and it can be done with pure PHP! it's aint framework, so it can be freely extract the portion of function only. which is the best ever tool for this case scenario (please advice if you know something better! Thanks)

- Setting FMailbox

Second, Implement concept of [@Ramon de la Fuente]. (Thanks @Ramon de la Fuente, google apps is good but it became history :P it's good when the time it's still free, while now hard to convince all clients use google apps. they may have their own exchange server installed on site, who know :))

- Setting client single email to catch all (*@email.com)

Third, Implement code of [@Nick]. (Thanks @Nick, due to privacy and confidential issues. clients email meant a lot to themselves too, we have to minimise the usage of thirdparty plugin. Although i love idea of cloudmailin)

- Implement Explode catch the email address part.

For sending, since the system defined to catch all. Simply predefine the field reply-to and FMailbox will catch it as well ;)

Thanks a lot for all the resources!!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main methods to achieve this

**Fetching the email from a mailbox**

In this method the email goes to a mailbox and you regularly check for content in this mailbox to process the email. While this generally causes a lag, you can reduce this by running a program regularly and having it poll the mailbox all the time.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971423/processing-incoming-e-mail-with-php-script)

**Redirecting mail processing to a program**

If your mail server is on unix, you can redirect email processing to a script where you can process the email as you wish

[Related question outside SO](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/7997-email-process.html)

Specifically it may be easiest to find a web host that supports procmail scripts. These configuration scripts allow you to redirect email to a PHP program and you can do this as a catchall for all email of a domain. See this [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752809/how-do-i-use-procmail-with-php)

Comment: most of the time we don't have control on client mail server. so i guess the second approach is not working for this case. (p.s: my client have their own mail server, and probably don't allow us to touch it while we're freelancing.) Do you have any idea on points 3 - 5 of the question? Thx for quick response ;)

Comment: Hi,sorry I didn't see the edit. You absolutely need to have control over the mail server to catch all aliases on the mail server. How about this: You register a domain name: hashcommunicator.com Then you can assign your client client1.hashcommunicator.com and you can control the email flow from your own mail server from there

Comment: it's okay dude :) may i have some keyword from you to do research, please. i would like to know more about.

Comment: I have inserted an example that uses procmail to redirect all email to a domain to a PHP script. From there you could read your unique conversation identifier (your hash) from the database and process the email accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly this with [cloudmailin](http://cloudmailin.com/) -- you just need to set up mail forwarding for all your public addresses to your cloudmailin address. So:

1. User emails randomly hashed address at, e.g. `info+dfj28d@example.com`
2. Mail server at example.com forwards all mail for `info` to `youraccount@cloudmailin.com`.
3. Cloudmailin posts email to your web site at `http://example.com/yourwebhook.php`.
4. Even though all mail is filtering through a single cloudmailin address, cloudmailin will include the original hashed to-address in the fields it posts, so your web site can extract the hash and determine which user is replying. Pseudo-PHP to give you an idea:

   ```
   <?php /* webhooks.php */
   $address = $_POST['to']; // 'info+dfj28d@example.com'
   $addressParts = explode('@', $address); // array('info+dfj28d', 'example.com')
   $userParts = explode('+', $addressParts[0]); // array('info', 'dfj28d');
   $hash = $userParts[0]; // 'dfj28d'
   ?>
   ```

In this example I'm using hashes like `info+dfj28d` because our mail domain was hosted on gmail, so gmail's `username+alias` syntax was an easy way to send all random hashes to the same mailbox. Other mail hosts have similar methods of creating wildcard aliases.

The point is you need both a random component (`dfj28d`), and a static component (`info`) in the address so your mail server can tell the difference between hashed addresses (anything that includes `info`) and regular mail accounts (`else@example.com`).

Answer (score 1):

We use Google Apps for a similar setup. http://www.google.com/apps/

We created a single "app@" account that receives all mail as a catchall. The app generates it's own email addresses for incoming email like yours. The app was written (php) to read the incoming email through IMAP.

*[ I'd advise using a separate domain set up specifically for your app by the way, that separates the mail servers and responsabilities and allows for the client to change/upgrade/reconfigure mailservers without breaking the app. ]*

You keep the ability to add "real" users to the Apps backend, which means you could forward "else@" if mail gets sent to it by accident.

Added benefits include:

- you get google spam filter.
- You get a webmail interface (gmail basically).
- You can add domains as aliases, so multiple domains are ease to set up. (**with a warning: you must add the domain as an alias, only the main Apps domain supports a catchall**)

---

Steps involved:

1. Set up google Apps on a domain. For email it involves DNS entries so a domain that is under your control servers best.
2. Add an account for your app, and set the catchall.
3. Build said app ;) Generating special email addresses shouldn't be a problem - we use formats like operation.000345@
4. Build the part that reads the incoming mail. http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php Our app moves mail from the inbox to either "AppArchive" or "AppInvalid" depending on wether we can find what the mail related to in the app. (also: easy debugging by dragging an AppInvalid back into the inbox).
5. Log in with your App account on the webmail client and watch the magic happen...

I could elaborate a little more on the IMAP code, but the idea should be clear.

---

(We also use Mandrill for a different project though - and their API seems like a good way to go as well)